# Measuring quantum states without violating no-cloning

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, linear-algebra, quantum-computer

In Nielsen and Chuang exercise 2.64, the following problem is given:

> Suppose Bob is given a quantum state chosen from a set $\{ \lvert \psi_1 \rangle, \ldots , \lvert \psi_m \rangle \}$ of linearly independent states [in some Hilbert space]. Construct a POVM $\{E_1, E_2, \ldots, E_{m+1} \}$ such that if outcome $E_i$ occurs, $1 \le i \le m$, then Bob knows with certainty that he was given the state $\lvert \psi_i \rangle$. (The POVM must be such that $\langle \psi_i | E_i | \psi_i\rangle > 0$ for each i.)

Here a POVM is a positive operator-valued measurement, or a set $\{E_i\}$ of positive operators satisfying the completeness condition
$$ \sum_i E_i = I. $$
Note also that the states $\lvert \psi_i \rangle$ are not necessarily orthogonal, they are only assumed to be linearly independent.

My approach to this problem is to construct each $E_i$ for $i \le m$ as a scaled projector:
$$ E_i = \alpha_i P_i, $$
where $P_i$ is the projector onto the orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{Span}(\lvert \psi_1 \rangle, \ldots, \lvert \hat{\psi_i} \rangle, \ldots, \lvert \psi_m \rangle)$ in $\mathrm{Span}(\lvert \psi_1 \rangle, \ldots, \lvert \psi_m \rangle)$ satisfying $\langle \psi_i | P_i | \psi_i \rangle > 0$, and $\alpha_i$ is some positive real number.

Then we have the desired properties that each $E_i$ is positive, and $\langle \psi_i | E_j | \psi_i \rangle = \delta_{ij} \beta_i$ for some real positive $\beta_i$. Indeed, $E_i$ has eigenvalues $\alpha_i$ and $0$; $E_j | \psi_i \rangle = 0$ if $i \ne j$ as $P_j$ is a projector onto a space orthogonal to $\lvert \psi_i \rangle$; and
$$\langle \psi_i | E_i | \psi_i \rangle = \alpha_i \cos \theta_i \langle \psi_i | \psi_i \rangle = \beta_i > 0, $$
where $\theta_i$ is the angle between $\lvert \psi_i \rangle$ and $P_i \lvert \psi_i \rangle$.

Then for any choice of $\{\alpha_i\}$ we have constructed positive $E_i$ for $i \le m$, but this set of positive operators is not necessarily complete. To complete the set, let $E_{m+1} = I - \sum_{i \le m} E_i$.  It seems that as long as we can ensure $E_{m+1}$ is positive, then we have constructed the desired POVM. However, I am not sure how to assign $\{\alpha_i\}$ in order to do so.

Naively, I can't see why we don't have a great deal of freedom over $\alpha_i$. As a sum of Hermitian operators, $E_{m+1}$ is automatically Hermitian. And $\langle \psi_i | E_{m+1} | \psi_i \rangle = \langle \psi_i | \psi_i \rangle - \beta_i \ge 0$ so long as $\alpha_i \cos \theta_i \le 1$. However, this so-called POVM would be able to distinguish the states $\lvert \psi_i \rangle$ perfectly if we were allowed to choose $\alpha_i = 1/\cos \theta_i$, in violation of the no-cloning theorem (as shown in Nielsen–Chuang, exercise 1.2).

Clearly there's something I'm missing, and I believe it might be in the criterion for $E_{m+1}$ to be positive. Is it sufficient for all $\langle \psi_i | E_{m+1} | \psi_i \rangle \ge 0$, given that $\lvert \psi_i \rangle$ are linearly independent?

Is this a fruitful approach for this problem? If so, what conditions on $\{\alpha_i\}$ (or, equivalently, $\{\beta_i\})$ would ensure $E_{m+1}$ is positive? What have I missed?

EDIT: I asked the same question in [Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4625153/condition-for-positive-semidefinite-operator-in-hilbert-space), and I got a helpful answer: one way to ensure $E_{m+1}$ is positive is to let $\alpha_i = \frac1m$ for all $i\le m$.

Comment: I think you want the beta_i to be 1 such that the outcome E_i ensures you the correct state is psi_i. Then the expectation value of E_i with any psi_j for j neq i should be zero. If this were not true, then the same E_i could say that the state is psi_j for j neq i with a certain probability. I think it's an extension of the example on the page preceding the page with the exercise. Also, if P_i projects on the orthogonal complement of psi_i, shouldn't the states psi_i and P_i psi_i have zero inner product?

Comment: In equations 2.118 - 2.120 an example is given for a solution in the case $m=2$, but I don't see where the coefficients in this example come from. In that example certainly $\beta_i < 1$.

Comment: I do have that measurement $E_j$ ensures that it can't be state $\psi_i$, for $i\ne j$ and $j \le m$. I agree that I would like to have $\beta_i=1$. However, since $\psi_i$ are not necessarily orthogonal, $\beta_i=1$ would violate no-cloning, and I must not be able to guarantee that a measurement of $E_{m+1}$ does not occur. Also, $P_i$ does not project to the orthogonal complement of $\psi_i$, it projects onto the orthogonal complement of the span of $\psi_j$ for $j\ne i$.

Comment: True, it might be that $\beta_i < 1$. Perhaps you need to make sure that $\langle \psi_i \vert E_j \vert \psi_i \rangle = 0$ for $j \neq i, m+1$. Then getting $E_{m+1}$ give you nothing but $E_i$ allows you to identify the state. So in that light $\langle \psi_i \vert E_{m+1} \vert \psi_i \rangle = 1 - \beta_i$.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I believe I already have $\langle\psi_i|E_j|\psi_i\rangle=0$ for $j\ne i$ and $j\le m$, no matter what $\alpha_i$ is. What I'm looking for is some reason that I can't simply let $\alpha_i=1/\cos\theta_i$, ensuring $\beta_i=1$.

Comment: If my equation above holds for $E_{m+1}$ you should be able to reconstruct the operator since you know how it acts on any of the basis states.

Comment: Yes I agree—I have the same equation in my question (though i do not assume that $\psi_i$ are normalized, so $\langle\psi_i|\psi_i\rangle$ is not necessarily $1$). But I need my construction to be a POVM. Unfortunately, if $\beta_i=\langle\psi_i|\psi_i\rangle$ were a valid measurement, it violate no-cloning. So I know I've made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Still, if $\beta_i \neq 1$ that should be enough. Even though you get outcome $E_i$ with probability $\beta_i < 1$, once you get it you are still sure that the state is $\psi_i$. Whilst if you get $E_{m+1}$ with probability $1 - \beta_i$ you don't know anything as long as $\langle \psi_j \vert E_{m+1} \vert \psi_j \rangle \neq 0$ for all $j \neq i$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142320/discussion-between-jackson-and-guliano).